# Spring @Value("${}") often null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-properties

I'm using Spring Boot application. In some `@Component` class `@Value` fields are loaded, instead on other classes they are always `null`.

Seems that `@Value`(s) are loaded after my `@Bean`/`@Component` are created.

I need to load some values from a properties file in my `@Bean`.

Have you some suggestion?

Comment: Are the "other classes" registered as spring beans? What is the difference between the ones that receive the values and the ones that don't?

Comment: Sure, they are or Bean or Component

Comment: Are you checking for the values in the constructor?

Answer (score 53):

The properties(and all of the bean dependencies) are injected after the bean is constructed(the execution of the constructor).

You can use constructor injection if you need them there.

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {
    private String prop;
    @Autowired
    public SomeBean(@Value("${some.prop}") String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
        //use it here
    }
}
```

Another option is to move the constructor logic in method annotated with `@PostConstruct` it will be executed after the bean is created and all it's dependencies and property values are resolved.

Comment: And who will call this constructor? I'm trying but this 'custom' constructor is not called.

Comment: You probably also have the default and the custom constructor. Remove the one without parameters.

Comment: I can't because I've an exception removing default constructor: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: it.modem.ModemManager.<init>()

Comment: Then try with the @PostConstruct method

Comment: I yet done it. It works but I'm not in the constructor. So is not possibile have values inside the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

It can happen when you are resolving it into a static variable. I had observed this sometime back and resolved it just by removing static. As people always say, exercise caution while using static.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("file:/your/file/path")
public class MyBean {

  private @Value("${property}") String property;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Using @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") I've an Exception during startup: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.core.io.Resource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}. Thanks

Comment: Did you annotated the class with `@Component` ?

Comment: Yes. @Evgeni has centered the problem. I can't user Value field inside the constructor as it is now.

Answer (score -2):

Another possible reason is that the '@Value' lines are below the lines that need these properties/values.

I spent a lot of time debugging this problem, and found out that the order of lines matters!