# Spring @Configuration file with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean doesn't resolve @Value annotation

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

I have following configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerConfig {

    @Value("${property:defaultValue}")
    private String property;

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc() throws IOException {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("properties/" + property + ".properties"));
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }
}
```

I run my application with following VM option:

```
-Dproperty=propertyValue
```

So I'd like my application to load specific property file on startup. But for some reason at this stage `@Value` annotations are not processed and property is `null`. On the other hand if I have `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` configured via xml file - everything works perfectly as expected. Xml file example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:properties/${property:defaultValue}.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If I try to to inject property value in another Spring configuration file - it is properly injected. If I move my `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean creation to that configuration file - field value is null again.

As workaround, I use this line of code:

```
System.getProperties().getProperty("property", "defaultValue")
```

Which is also works, but I'd like to know why such behavior is occurs and maybe it is possible to rewrite it in other way but without xml?

Comment: First I strongly suggest the use of `ProperySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and use a `@PropertySource` on your class. Second the bean needs to be `static`.

Comment: @M.Deinum `@PropertySource` works perfectly for me, but what if I have custom implementation of `ProperySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`?

Comment: Why would you need a custom implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum to load properties from ZooKeeper for example

Comment: You  don't need a custom implementation for that you need a custom `PropertySource`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From Spring [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This happens automatically when using context:property-placeholder in XML, but must be explicitly registered using a static @Bean method when using @Configuration classes. See the "Working with externalized values" section of @Configuration's javadoc and "a note on BeanFactoryPostProcessor-returning @Bean methods" of @Bean's javadoc for details and examples.

So, you are trying to use a placeholder in the code block required to enable placeholder processing.

As @M.Deinum mentioned, you should use a PropertySource (default or custom implementation).

Example below shows how to use properties in a PropertySource annotation as well as how to inject properties from the PropertySource in a field.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(
          value={"classpath:properties/${property:defaultValue}.properties"},
          ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class ConfigExample {

    @Value("${propertyNameFromFile:defaultValue}")
    String propertyToBeInjected;

    /**
     * Property placeholder configurer needed to process @Value annotations
     */
     @Bean
     public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     }
}
```

---

## Update 09/2021

as Koray mentioned in the comment, the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is not needed anymore since Spring 4.3+ / Spring Boot 1.5+. Dynamic filenames can be used for property files in `@PropertySource` and `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations without additional configuration.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(
          value={"classpath:properties/${property:defaultValue}.properties"},
          ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class ConfigExample {

    @Value("${propertyNameFromFile:defaultValue}")
    String propertyToBeInjected;
}
```

```
@ConfigurationProperties("properties/${property:defaultValue}.properties")
public class ConfigExample {

    String propertyNameFromFile;
}
```

Comment: What if i want to add additional properties in the bean creation method? I am loading my yaml file properties manually and want that to add in the PropertySources

Comment: I think _Property placeholder configurer needed to process @Value annotations_  is not true anymore since Spring 4.3 and `propertyConfigurer()` can be removed from the example?

Answer (score 7):

For any other poor souls who couldn't get this to work in some Configuration classes when they work in others:

Look to see what other beans you have in that class and if any of them get instantiated early in the ApplicationContext. A ConversionService is an example of one. This would instantiate the Configuration class before what is required is registered, thereby making no property injection take place.

I fixed this by moving the ConversionService to another Configuration class that I Imported.

Comment: Another possibility is to use constructor injection, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636060/spring-value-often-null

Comment: If the first answer doesn't work, this is likely to be the case. It saved me a lot of head scratch.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your application using VM option and then want to access that option in your application you have to do it slightly different:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties.property}")
private String property;
```

Your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is not aware of system properties, also note that you are accessing properties using `$` - which refers to place holders and `#` refers to beans, where `systemProperties` is a bean.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in configuration where I have PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean creation, but works in any another configuration file