# Spring @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm Spring newbie and I'm wondering what are prerequisites/conditions of using @Value annotation in Spring?

What I have for now is a Token class which has hardcoded secret key as a field. What I'm trying to do is to move this secret key to config file to eliminate hardcoding but for some reason the following is not working.

```
public class Token {
//...some code

    @Value("${my.secretKey}")
    private String key;

//...some code
}
```

Maybe there is any standard technique to solving this type of tasks.
Thanks for help!

p.s. I have `.properties` file which contains `my.secretKey=123` entry.

Comment: Maybe related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344895/spring-configuration-file-with-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-bean-doesnt-resol/33370122#33370122

Comment: @Reimeus, could you please clarify what info it is required to provide? To speak frank, it is almost a new project with a couple of classes.

Comment: have a properties file, define them in **applicationcontext**, use them as you are using.

Comment: Is the instance of the `Token` class a Spring bean? If you create a new instance yourself by using `new Token()` then Spring injection does not work; Spring cannot set the value of the `key` variable.

Comment: @superbob, the thing is that my token is not a configuration class. It is a class I create by myself using java new.

Comment: @Jesper are you saying that I can't use value annotation with classes that are not spring beans? Thanks, didn't find it anywhere in documentation.

Comment: If you create objects yourself with `new` then Spring doesn't get a chance to do things like dependency injection and injecting values. Such things only work on objects that are created through Spring (Spring beans).

Comment: From the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html): "Property values can be injected directly into your **beans** using the @Value" (that's spring-boot but same thing)

Comment: @Jesper, thank you very much. Could you please post your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Injecting dependencies and values only works on objects that are managed by Spring - when you manually create an object using `new`, for example by doing `new Token()`, then Spring cannot process the object to inject dependencies and values.

The `Token` object must be a Spring bean for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

To use `@Value` annotation your Spring version must be `3.0+`

You must register a static `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in either XML or annotation, so that Spring `@Value` know how to interpret `${}`

For more information

https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-value-default-value/

Answer (score 0):

One mistake can also be in proper location of `.properties` file. Your `.properties` file location is very important. Your `xyz.properties` file must be place in your project's `src` folder, like : `src/xyz.properties` 
After that,
**Load your properties file in the XML config file :**
File: `applicationContext.xml`
Add the following lines:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:xyz.properties"/>
```

This code should appear just after the `<context:component-scan .../>` line in your xml config file.
And now 
Inject the properties values into your  `Token` class, It should work now.
Happy Coding.