# Spring Boot: external messages.properties are being added but not used

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I have two `messages.properties` files. One is located inside `resources` and another one is outside my .jar file in a directory called `etc`.

This is my PropertiesConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);

        final List<Resource> resourceLst = new ArrayList<Resource>();

        resourceLst.add(new FileSystemResource("etc/application.properties"));
        resourceLst.add(new FileSystemResource("etc/messages.properties"));
        resourceLst.add(new FileSystemResource("etc/messages_et.properties"));

        ppc.setLocations(resourceLst.toArray(new Resource[]{}));

        return ppc;
    }
}
```

In the logs I see this:

```
11:18:43.764  INFO [main] PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer              - Loading properties file from file [C:\Users\deniss\IdeaProjects\repgen\etc\application.properties]
11:18:43.764  WARN [main] PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer              - Could not load properties from file [C:\Users\deniss\IdeaProjects\repgen\etc\application.properties]: etc\application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
11:18:43.764  INFO [main] PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer              - Loading properties file from file [C:\Users\deniss\IdeaProjects\repgen\etc\messages.properties]
11:18:43.764  INFO [main] PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer              - Loading properties file from file [C:\Users\deniss\IdeaProjects\repgen\etc\messages_et.properties]
```

As I understand my `messages.properties` from `etc` is loaded. Although when the application is working, the values from it are not used. They are coming from default `messages.properties` inside my `resources` project folder. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You want a message source, but you are using property placeholder

Comment: @sashok_bg you are correct. I have added another @Configuration bean to my project. `@Bean
 public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {` The problem is that I don't know how to point `messageSource.setBasename("");` to the files outside my .jar. `"classpath"` obviously doesn't work.

Comment: According to spring docs, it is only possible to add a classpath, meaning inside the .jar Too bad.

Comment: You can add anything to your classpath in theory

Comment: @sashok_bg that is true. I found a solution by using setBaseName("file:etc/messages"). This now loads my messages.properties files from outside folder.

Comment: **watch out!** assume you have file `path/to/messages_en.properties` on base name you have to set : `messageSource.setBasename("file:path/to/messages")` **omitting the suffix**  `_en.properties`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an answer for this question here:
[Spring Boot and multiple external configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files)

That worked for me earlier, so it is worth to give it a try!

Comment: I have tried those solutions and I still get the same result. I think that has something to do that messages properties file require a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

my solution was:

```
@Configuration   
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("file:/path/to/file/messages");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10); //reload every 10 sec..
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

it works perfect on me, remember **to omitt the suffix _et.properties** on the base name, for example if you have a file named `messages_et.properties` set base name will result : `messageSource.setBasename("file:/path/to/file/messages");`

Comment: How do I actually get a message from that default `messages.properties` (with no suffix in its name)? I am asking, because the `MessageSource`-object always requires a Locale and even if I give it `Locale#getDefault` the default properties-file is not queried. And of course there is no fallback unless I specify the default value as a string - which would render the default `messages.properties` file useless.

Comment: In my case it had to be like  "file:\\C:\\users\\user\\messages\\labels", my files are named labels.properties and labels_es.properties. I am using windows 10,

Answer (score -1):

First Of all , clear about configuration setting of Spring Boot.

In POM.XML,  Confirm once Layout as "ZIP"

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>  <!-- added -->
                <layout>ZIP</layout> <!-- to use PropertiesLaunchar -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Because ,For the PropertiesLauncher the layout is "ZIP" and make sure avoid to use @EnableAutoConfiguration.

or Use @PropertySource annotation for external properties.
( Refer :[Spring Boot PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)).

This Topic already discussed by StackOverflow.

Refer :

[Spring Boot: Is it possible to use external application.properties files in arbitrary directories with a fat jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140784/spring-boot-is-it-possible-to-use-external-application-properties-files-in-arbi)

[Spring @Configuration file with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean doesn't resolve @Value annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344895/spring-configuration-file-with-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-bean-doesnt-resol)

Comment: There is nothing about application.properties in my post. I am asking about messages.properties. This is different. Application.properties work fine with my current setup without the mentioned adjustments from your side.